# A knowing B and B knowing A in real life scenarios.

Tags: probability

This thought is coming from this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/gfsai5/dragon_soul_win_rate_infographic/) where they discuss that 62% of the games won were by teams taking the first dragon. I was thinking that it might be misleading, because what might actually be happening is that winning teams are taking the first dragon instead.

What this means is that I'm trying to understand the difference between these two:

1. The teams that won took first dragon 62% of the times.
2. The teams that took first dragon won 62% of the times.

And in maths:

1. P ( FirstDragon = True | Win = True )
2. P ( Win = True | FirstDragon = True )

Now, the events have mutually exclusive results. One team wins and the other team does not win. One team takes the first dragon and the other team does not take the first dragon.

To make it a little easier, I wrote some possible results:

- Win = True & FirstDragon = True
- Win = True & FirstDragon = True
- Win = True & FirstDragon = True
- Win = True & FirstDragon = False
- Win = True & FirstDragon = False
- Win = False & FirstDragon = True
- Win = False & FirstDragon = True
- Win = False & FirstDragon = False
- Win = False & FirstDragon = False
- Win = False & FirstDragon = False

And calculating the probabilities of before:

1. P ( FirstDragon = True | Win = True ) = 3/5
2. P ( Win = True | FirstDragon = True ) = 3/5

It makes sense if we look at Bayes theorem:

P(A|B) * P(B) = P(B|A) * P(A)

Since the probability of FirstDragon is 50% and the probability of winning is 50%, both options 1 and 2 end up being the same

But the questions still remain:

- Intuitively, it doesn't make sense that both these sentences mean the same thing.
- I still think it might be misleading to state that teams taking the first dragons win more, because trying to force the first dragon and taking it should not necessarily result in more wins. I think it's actually the opposite. Winning teams tend to take the first dragon.

So what's the truth here? I'm certain that there are cases where this does not occur. And I'm certain that it's possible for someone to mislead the reader by purposefully choosing the right probability (equation 1 or 2) depending on what makes it look more favorable.

Comment: There is a joke about some recent graduates interviewing for a job as a statistician at a particular company.  During the first person's interview they get to the question "What is 2+2?" to which he replies "4".  During the second person's interview he replied to that question "It depends on what you mean, for example in $\Bbb Z_4$ you have $2+2=0$."  On the third person's interview when asked what $2+2$ is, he looks around shiftily making sure there isn't anyone listening in, leans in close and says "What do you *want* $2+2$ to be?"  The third person got the job.

Comment: That all said, statisticians can and do often choose representations of the data which help advance their desired narrative.  Something to keep in mind however is the difference between correlation and causation.  While the winning teams may be more likely to have taken the first dragon, and the teams who take the first dragon being more likely to win, I would wager that this is less a reflection of the strength and importance of taking the first dragon and more as a general reflection of player skill, team composition, and general rhythm of how the game progresses.

Comment: I think it is a mistake to forego any conventional wisdom and strategy for the purpose of trying to take the dragon early just to say you did when the current flow of the game does not lend itself to giving you a safe opportunity to do so.  If you are in the lead and just won an important teamfight (*which is something the stronger team is more likely to do*) then during that opportunity try to take the dragon, but don't try to do this while the other team can just ambush you during your attempt and steal it from you.

Comment: @JMoravitz Apologies for this comment, but I never heard that joke before. Great joke! My area of study, as of now, is geared more towards advanced Real/Complex Analysis, but I'll be using that joke myself now since it expresses a lot of conceptual aspects among several branches of Mathematics. =)